# How to Remove String Result

Tags: php, instagram

Below is the code I am using

```
$decode = json_decode($json, true); 
var_dump($decode[data][0][id]);
```

This results in the below:

```
string(28) "817826618678707293_483148328"
```

How to remove string(28) ??
example results :

```
817826618678707293_483148328
```

Comment: Use `print_r()` in place of `var_dump`

Comment: your result is a string containing 817826618678707293_483148328. The `string(28)` is just a representation. Does it error in the rest of your code?

Answer (score -1):

Replace var_dump() with print_r()

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/gaul/media/recent?access_token=1463408808.e757b44.0738048e481448b48f1cbb23f70f0195&count=1'); 
$decode = json_decode($json, true); 
print_r($decode[data][0][id]);
```

var_dump — Dumps all the information about a variable

print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable

Hope this will help.
Regards

Comment: sry .. i just post the part of the code provided above.. it won't run here..I made the possible change. Thanks for noticing